# child theme style.css not updating on WordPress | include css from child and parent theme

Tags: css, wordpress, function, themes

/*include **CSS from child** and parent theme | **style.css** not updating on WordPress*/

```
 function mychildtheme_enqueue_styles() {
        $parent_style = 'parent-style';
        wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' ); // parent css
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom-style.css', array(), rand(111,9999), 'all' ); // custom child css
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), rand(111,9999), 'all' ); // child css     
    } 
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mychildtheme_enqueue_styles' ); // **register hook**
```

/* here the code for incude the *custom CSS* in your child theme */

Answer (score 0):

```
/*include CSS from child and parent theme | style.css not updating on WordPress*/

function mychildtheme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style';
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom-style.css', array(), rand(111,9999), 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), rand(111,9999), 'all' );
    
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mychildtheme_enqueue_styles' ); // register hook
```